# What is the difference between Reformat Code and Rearrange Code in Jetbrains IDEs?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, reformatting

These are options that can be found under the **Code** dropdown menu. Both of them seem to arrange the code in a similar manner.

Answer (score 16):

There are 2 things that we might want to do after writing a piece of code:

1. Order all the attributes in a certain way, like arrange them in ascending/descending order alphabetically.
2. Remove the extra spaces/tabs that we might have given and arrange them in a proper indented format.

**Rearrange code** just does the 1st point, arranges it according to android code style guidelines. **Reformat code** does both 1st and 2nd point.

Answer (score 8):

Rearranging code does more things than just reformat the code.

As mentioned in the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/rearranging-code-using-arrangement-rules.html), you can also change the placement of variables as well and define some custom rules which will be used when you rearrange the code.